# What should be approach to understand a new project

Tags: java

If one joins a new project, how should that person approach it if
there is no documentation of the code and program is quite big to understand. Team members are also not that much informative.
Should the person debug the code line by line?But it can be highly time consuming and exhaustive.

Comment: For what purpose? Code Review? Fixing a bug? Coding new functionality?

Comment: As I have to develop the code further, so I need to understand what code already does.

Comment: Do you have access to the users of the project? If so, talk to them. Ask them what they like and dislike about it. Say you're here to help.

Comment: I don't have access to users.

Comment: Regarding the downvotes: maybe you should have asked this question on http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ While it is programming related, it does not fit the [topics you can ask here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: OK.Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options:

1. Look for manuals. I have seen projects without specification and developer documentation, but had a manual.
2. Participate in a training, if offered by your company. This may take some time, e.g. the next training is in 2 months.
3. Run the code and see what it does.
4. get a tool like [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) that visualizes the dependencies. By that, find the central modules or classes. Look at those first.
5. Ask your developer colleagues. If they don't want to tell you, tell them that you need some understanding in order to do your job
6. If all of the before does not help, ask your boss for help. He should have a plan to get you productive.

The users option would be great, but in all companies I worked for I did not have access to end users as well, since we always worked with partners as intermediate resellers. Contacting the partners is not a good idea, because it might leave a negative impression if you don't know the software.